# .hgignore for VB.Net (Express)?

Tags: vb.net, mercurial, hgignore

I didn't see a question on this subject in the archives, so here goes: For those of you experienced Mercurial users, is this a correct .hgignore file to tell VB.Net Express to ignore files/sub-dirs when adding items in a new repository?

bin
 obj
 temp
 *.user
 *.suo
 *.ncb

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

well you either need to start each line with glob: or have the first line

```
syntax:glob
```

mine (for C#) has Thumbs.db as well.

edit: you can also set up a global ignore list using your global [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui)

Comment: Thanks. Since it's recommended to create a repository for each project, I'll end up with copy/pasting a .hgignore file in all those. Does someone know if Mercurial supports reading from a common file before checking whether the given project has one of its own?

Comment: It appears you can put .hgignore in a number of places depending on if you want a per repository, per user, or per machine default ignore. Vist http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html and following the example locations for the hgrc file.  According to the mercurial docs .hgignore works the same.

Comment: hgrc also contains an ignore section in ui section